# subprocess cp destination file empty

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm writing a script which writes it's output to a system directory. Rather than run the entire script using root permissions, I'm writing the output to a temporary file and only using elevated privileges when copying the temporary file to the output.

```
print(tempfile.read())
return_code = suprocess.call(['/usr/bin/sudo', 'cp', tmpfile.name, outfile])
if return_code != 0:
    print('Copy failed')
    sys.exit(1)
return_code = subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/sudo', 'chmod', '664', outfile])
with open(outfile) as f2:
    print(f2.read())
```

The first debug prints out the expected contents of the generated file, but the second dprint is empty. In addition, inspecting the file in the filesystem says the file is `0` bytes in length and owned by root.

I've tried the following and it doesn't seem to make a difference:

- using `shell=True`
- using a `tempfile.NamedTempfile` or creating a temporary file myself and cleaning up

Comment: does it prompt for the sudo password?

Comment: yes, I'm prompted for the password. I might need to wait for user input... Not sure how though. Actually, no the script doesn't continue until after the password has been entered.

Comment: what do you mean? doed it not wait for user to enter password? (ie it just shows the prompt?)

Comment: yes it does, but I just had to check that it does.

Comment: is `tempfile` the variable name of the filename string? or is `tempfile.name` ? what is `tempfile.name`? (since earlier you reference `open(tempfile)` which usually wants a string unless you overrode open or something...

Comment: `tempfile.name` is the name of a `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` instance. The `open(tempfile)` is a typo in the question. Fixed.

Comment: @Joran OK, I've sorted it out. I still had the file open for writing when I attempted to copy the file, so I guess that the write hadn't flushed when I copied the file. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem. `tempfile` was still open for writing when `cp` was called and the write hadn't flushed to disk when the copy was attempted.